# C# linq subquery perfomance for interpreted and local queries

Tags: c#, linq

Well I have two queries, one connects to the database and get customer information (interpreted) and second just filter a local customer list objects (local).

```
var _db = new EFDbContext();
var query = from c in _db.Customers
            select new {
            c.Name,
            Purchases = from p in _db.Purchases
            where p.CustomerID == c.ID && p.Price > 100
            select new {p.Description, p.Price}
            };
```

And second

```
List<Customer> = new List<Customer> {  new Customer { }, ... };
List<Purchases> = new List<Purchases> { new Purchase { } , ... };

var query = from c in Customers
            select new {
            c.Name,
            Purchases = from p in Purchases
            where p.CustomerID == c.ID && p.Price > 100
            select new {p.Description, p.Price}
            };
```

For the performance reasons what would be the best choice for interpreted and local queries? Is it better to use joins or remain as it is.

Comment: You should take this advice from Eric Lippert: [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I want to understand how ienumerable and iqueryable works behind the scene

Comment: Queries based on `IEnumerable<T>` run **in memory** so are **very very fast**. Queries based on `IQueryable<T>` are (generally) converted into SQL and are run on a database, so they are **relatively slow**. If you're running the same query on in-memory objects versus database records then there should be no competition at all. In-memory is blindly faster.

Comment: The question you should really be asking is "Is it better to load raw records into memory and perform an `IEnumerable<T>` query on them or is it better to do a `IQueryable<T>` query? But that's when you need to race your horses.

Comment: Are you getting the feeling that no matter how many answers you get you can't tell which of your two queries is better? (Unless you race them **yourself**.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for the second query is better to use joins, and for the first remains as it is. Because for interpreted queries the outer and subquery are passed as a unit, avoiding unnecessary round -tripping, With local queries every combination outer and inner queries must be enumerated first. Am i mistake?

Comment: This makes no sense. You could easily have a database with a billion records in table A and a two records in table B. A join in memory would be far slower than a database join in this case. Equally you could have a thousand records that join with a thousand records which could yield a million joined records, so an in-memory query would be much much faster.

Comment: @Enigmativity It depends of how you interpret the OP question. In fact I was going to post the same as Nika, because the way I understand the question is whether one and the same **style** of query can be used in `Linq to Entities` and `Linq To Objects`. And the answer is unfortunately no. In the first case query provider can optimize it (in fact can and will generate SQL JOIN) while in second one have to use `Join` explicitly if wants to get a good performance.

Comment: @IvanStoev - Given that both queries are performed against the same data then the chances of the second one being slower, given that the data is already in memory, is exceptionally unlikely - the exact opposite of what you just said. This is just an impossible question to answer with anything meaningful.

Comment: @Enigmativity You and all other posters in this thread assume the question is to compare the performance of the two queries. What I'm sayinng is that the question is about **how** to write the query (1) **when** you have a database and (2) **when** you have a memory collections.

Comment: @IvanStoev - No, I'm not making that assumption at all. I'm saying that no matter how you construct the queries you can not, for sure, say that one way will be faster than the other. There are certainly ways to write the queries to suit different contexts, the query is only one factor of many and it is possible to nobble one horse to allow the other to win.

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree, and that's the idea of query language. And it sort of applies to `IQueryable`. But for `IEnumerable` is definitely matters how you write the query because in addition to the desired result you also specify the execution plan. I mean, if we take the OP example with lists, you **do** know it's generally inefficient - O(N * M) compared to `Join` which theoretically is O(N) due to hashing the right side sequence key.

Answer (score 1):

Well if I got your question correctly, 
The `Join` operator takes the rows from the first table, then takes only the rows with a matching key from the second table. This is much more efficient, because it doesn't need to perform as many operations.

While The query with multiple tables and a `Where` condition performs a Cartesian product of all the tables, then filters the rows that satisfy the condition. 
This means the Where condition is evaluated for each combination of rows (for example - n1 * n2 * n3 * n4).

I hope it satisfies your question.

Comment: This also doesn't make sense. A join performed on a database between two tables with 10,000 records each _could_ produce up to 100,000,000 results. Pulling the result across the network is much slower than pulling 2 x 10,000 across the network and doing a Cartesian product in memory.

Comment: my answer to your comment: everything hinges on how well the database engine is able to optimize the query for you,  it also comes down to the physical database file itself and its fragmentation level and even the storage technology you use to store the database files on

Comment: Exactly why it is impossible to answer this question in a way that is meaningful for the OP.

Comment: Saying that, my answer (depending on DB type) is well address his question

Answer (score 0):

**i Think Second scenario is better for you** just because when you use First approch then your query every time point out to your context and then load whole your Database in each and every query. so that process are so time consuming when your database size are large.

and in second scenario  that load whole database in one time and then store that data in local list so that make faster your performance of query because that not call every time dbcontext and load whole database they make localy query on each list.
so second approach are best.

refer below link to get exact difference between
[IEnumerable VS IQueryable](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/I8SY160612-IEnumerable-VS-IQueryable.html)

I think this are help you.

Comment: I think for  the second query is better to use joins, and for the first remains as it is. Because for interpreted queries the outer and subquery are passed as a unit, avoiding unnecessary round -tripping, With local queries every combination outer and inner queries must be enumerated first

Comment: As per Eric Lippert's blog post - "Even if by sheer chance you got an accurate answer, how would you have any confidence in its accuracy?" You don't know how complex the data is, how slow the network is, how the records are indexed. There is no way to know which will be faster.

Comment: @Enigmativity just make simple program for this and try out i tested that second approch are better.

Comment: @kap - Yes, but racing two horses doesn't mean that you know the outcome of every horse race in the future. Only the OP can tell which of their horses is faster in their situation.

Comment: @Enigmativity yup you are right but in this scenario  that Dbcontext are loaded only first time not every time.. suppose you are making burgur so can you go every time to get items that need to make burgur?  or can you take whole items in single time ?
 i think this example help you

Comment: @kap - That again doesn't make sense. Suppose I am making burgers and I get all of the buns, all of the meat patties and all of the cheese slices in one go and then build my burgers it could easily be slower than getting each item as needed. Lets say I have 1,000,000 buns, 1,000,000 meat patties, and 3 cheese slices. I would have to go collect 2,000,003 items, but I could only make 3 burgers. In this case it would be far better to query the database and only collect 3 buns, 3 meat patties & 3 cheese slices.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes but that are depend on your Databse and usage of that.

Comment: @kap - Exactly my point. Your usage is different from the OP's usage so you can't possibility know if what works for you will work for them.